# gensim KeyedVectors object word count

Tags: gensim

I load a KeyedVectors model and the word frequency seems like word index

And I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single-file format loaded by `load_word2vec_format()` doesn't include word counts – so they can't appear in the loaded object.

The usual convention is to put such files in most-frequent to least-frequent order, though. So in the absence of true count information, a plug value is used that decreases from the vocabulary-size to 1. (That's the number that's somewhat like the word index you're seeing.)

There's a way in some software to save extra info in a separate file – see the `fvocab` option of gensim's `save_word2vec_format()` and `load_word2vec_format()`. So perhaps that's already available with your vectors, and you can use that option.